# Solve 2 connected ODEs describing a domain

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

This problem confused me for a long time. I have 2 ODEs which describe part of our domain. They are connected at middle:
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} u = -a, x<x_0 
$$
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} u - \frac{u}{b^2}= 0, x>x_0 
$$
The whole domain is defined as
$$
-W < x  
$$
With the following conditions
$$
\lim_{x->-W} u = 0  
$$
$$
\lim_{x->+\infty} u = c \;\;or\;\; \lim_{x->L} u = c 
$$

```
u, u' and u'' needs to be continous.
```

a, b, W and c are constants. If not possible with $\infty$ one can replace $+\infty$ with a constant L.

---

Update: As a hint, the following functions are solutions of individual equations

$$u_1(x) = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma  $$
    $$u_2(x) = c_1 exp(-x/b) + c_2 exp(x/b) $$
Where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants related to the constants in the ODEs.

**Problem is that we usually put $c_2 = 0$ since the exp(x/b) diverges.
    If we do so, 2nd derivative of u would not be continous at $x_0$.**

---

My numerical simulated solution looks like 
$$ \frac{1}{1+exp(x/b)}$$
But it does't match exactly.
The form of numerical solution and 2 regions are clear in the following link:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281%2Bexp%28x%29%29+from+x%3D-10+to+x%3D10

Answer (score 2):

Ok:

- You have: 
  $$u(x) \equiv \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  u_1(x) = \alpha e^{-x/b} + \beta e^{x/b} & \text{if } x > x_0 \\
  u_2(x) = -a x^2 + \gamma x + \delta      & \text{if } x < x_0 
  \end{array} \right. $$
- Because of boundedness at $x \to \infty$, we must set $\beta = 0$.
- Because of boundedness at $x \to -\infty$, the only solution satisfying this would be that whereas $a = 0$ (which is a given constant) and, of course, $\gamma = 0$, so we have: 
  $$ \delta = c.$$
  Otherwise, if $a \neq 0$, the solution is unbounded at $x \to \infty$.
- Then we arrive at:

$$u(x) \equiv \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
u_1(x) = \alpha e^{-x/b}  & \text{if } x > x_0 \\
u_2(x) = c                & \text{if } x < x_0 
\end{array} \right. $$

- Now it's time to ensure continuity at $x = x_0$ by setting $u_1(x_0) = u_2(x_0)$, which gives us the value of $\alpha$ as a function of $b$ and $c$.
- Note that we'll have also differentiability for certain values of $c$, which is also given in the problem. Can you take it from here?

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

PD: Forgive me for changing your notation.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the boundary from $-\infty$ to $-W_D$. This problem is related to some physics which a constant doesn't make sense. My numerical simulated solution looks like $1/(1+exp(x/a))$ but not exactly.

Comment: Hi @Dmoreno, But that equation is correct for $x>x_0$ not $x<x_0$ and -W.

Comment: Hi again. In that case you have the new condition: $$-a W^2 - \gamma W + \delta = 0,$$ while nothing else changes. This leads to a problem where $\alpha, \gamma$ and $\delta$ are not known. The conditions of continuity and differentiability (1st and 2nd derivative) will give you the values of the three unknowns. I'm afraid that these values will strongly depend on the choice of $W$.

Comment: Maybe a more detailed description of the physics of your problem would give us a hint of the behaviour of the solution.

Comment: My numerical solution looks like something like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281%2Bexp%28x%29%29+from+x%3D-10+to+x%3D10

Comment: Then, I'm not sure if your condition $u(x \to -\infty) = 0$ is adequate enough. Shouldn't it be $u'(x \to -\infty) = 0$?

Comment: I see, that also works.

Comment: Happy to help, @Hesam.